# How to convert/translate/replace '[A-Z]' ,'[1-26]' usning XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Hi i have an requirement to translate/convert/replace

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ''1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526' 
first i am translating
 <xsl:variable name="lowercase2uppercase"
            select="translate($mystring,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
```

here i need to translate those 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' to '1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526'.
for example letter 'A', 'B' to 'Z'i am translating like this

```
<xsl:when test="$letter='A'">
    <xsl:attribute name="letter">01</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$letter='B'">
    <xsl:attribute name="letter">02</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$letter='j'">
    <xsl:attribute name="letter">10</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
.........## Heading ##
<xsl:when test="$letter='Z'">
    <xsl:attribute name="letter">26</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

here , i can do like this but the solution is too lengthy, i need a generic solution to replace [A-Z] with [1-26] using XSLT.
please help me . 
If `my $letter` is `'j'` it is giving 00 instead 10 likewise for `'t'` also it is giving 10 instead of 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using this function?

```
normalize-space(concat(
                translate($letter, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                   '00000000011111111112222222'), 
                translate($letter, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                   '12345678901234567890123456')))
```

It's still pretty concise and it does what you want. :-)

Comment: thanks, it is working for all cases except 10 and 20.
if my $letter consists j it is giving 00 instead 10 like wise for 't' also it is giving 10 instead of 20.

can you simplify this like this 

<xsl:when test="$letter='A'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="letter">01</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>

<xsl:when test="$letter='j'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="letter">10</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>

Comment: @user3549914 If you break down what the expression is actually trying to do you'll see the fix for yourself.  The `translate` function replaces each character in the first string with the character at the same position in the second string.  The first `translate` deals with the first digit of the two digit number, or space if it's just one digit.  For the first nine letters there's no "first digit", for the next ten the digit needs to be 1, and for the remaining seven it needs to be 2.

Comment: @user3549914 There was a typo in this function which I have now fixed. Try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you define a variable, like so...

```
<xsl:variable name="replace" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
```

Then you could simplify the 'translation' of one letter, like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before($replace, $letter)) + 1" />
```

And to do it on a whole string, you would use a recursive template, where you replaced one letter at a time.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="replace" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template match="word" >
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:call-template name="translate">
       <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
       </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="translate">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:if test="$text != ''">
      <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($text, 1, 1)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before($replace, $letter)) + 1" />
      <xsl:call-template name="translate">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 2, string-length($text) -1 )" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<word>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</word>
```

The following is output

```
<word>1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526</word>
```